# Wordpress - WPBakery - Near Footer jump issue

Tags: plugins

I have a wordpress site @ https://www.oxygenband.com/ and got a page jumping issue @ https://www.oxygenband.com/wedding-music-band-in-chennai/

When you scroll to the bottom of the page above footer, the page starts to jump infinitely.

The issue is not happening on following conditions:

- When I remove the section `Opt for Oxygen-Band` to `Read more`
- When I remove the footer
- When I deactivate the `Wolf WPBakery Page Builder Extension` extension. But that plugin is part of my theme and disabling it messes up the layout.

But on following scenarios, it is happening:

- When I replace the `Opt for Oxygen-Band` to `Read more` section with a simple Heading widget.
- When I replace the `Opt for Oxygen-Band` to `Read more` section with a simple text widget.
- When I replace the `Opt for Oxygen-Band` to `Read more` section with a Content block section.

Is there a way I could debug the issue to any specific script or line of code and fix it?

Comment: Your site just says Error establishing database connection, are you sure this isn't a pure CSS bug? You might be limiting your options by only asking in WordPress communities, rather than general CSS. Note that this could be an issue with WP Bakery or your theme, and support for 3rd party themes and plugins is offtopic and out of scope

Comment: Site is up now. I somehow assumed its a JS issue. Will re-think in CSS perspective. Also, I will try contacting theme author. Guess that might help.

Comment: I took a look and could not reproduce the issue, I wasn't sure what to expect when you said "jump infinitely" either but I saw no problems and it scrolled normally